# How to print a value with the same criteria - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print numbers that are divisible by 3 and 5.
For numbers divisible by 3, print out "Fizz".
For numbers divisible by 5, print out "Buzz".
For numbers divisible by both 3 and 5, print out "FizzBuzz" in 
the console. Otherwise, just print out the number.

Tried these codes:

```
var i;

for(i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
  if(i % 3 === 0){
     console.log("Fizz");   
  }else if(i % 5 === 0){
     console.log("Buzz");   
 }else if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0){
      console.log("FizzBuzz");
  }else {
   console.log(i);      
}
}
```

But it seems it passing out the 3rd else if...
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: According to [Marijn Haverbeke](http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html), this is actually an interview question that has been claimed to weed out a significant percentage of programmer candidates. So if you didn't solve it, you’re not allowed to feel good about your chances in that interview.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado,  very funny.

Answer (score 2):

You could move the combined comparsion to top of the comparisons, because if both conditions are true, you need not to check the others.

```js
var i;

for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) { // check first, includes
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {         // this comparison and
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {         // this as well.
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0)` can't we have `if (i % 15 === 0)` ?

Comment: right, but i think the question is about the order of comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Less code for same results:

```js
for(var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  var output = '';
  if(i % 3 === 0) output += 'Fizz';
  if(i % 5 === 0) output += 'Buzz';
  console.log(output.length > 0 ? output : i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A number divisible by two numbers must be divisible by their [Least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple), which in this case is 15. You also have to move this check up, so that it's considered before the other statements.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 15 == 0)
        console.log('FizzBuzz');
    else if (i % 3 === 0)
        console.log("Fizz");
    else if (i % 5 === 0)
        console.log("Buzz");
    else
        console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i;

for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) { 
        document.write("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {         
        document.write("Fizz");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {      
        document.write("Buzz");
    } else {
       document.write(i);
    }
}
```